# Select before specific date from one day only

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to retrieve data from MySQL from one day, but I don't know the interval between two rows (there may be 4 rows from one day and a gap of a week for example).

Let's say I have: *(following isn't code)*

```
3 rows where date = 2015-06-15
1 row where date = 2015-06-09
4 rows where date = 2015-06-05
```

I want to retrieve all 4 rows from 2015-06-05 with

```
[...] WHERE `date` < '2015-06-07'
```

or only one row from 2015-06-09 with

```
[...] WHERE `date` < '2015-06-14'
```

Is that possible with SQL only?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `WHERE date(`date`) = '2015-06-05'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to receive one days worth of rows before a given date.  I think that would be:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(t2.date) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.`date` < '2015-06-07')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
select * from table
where date  = (select max(date) from table where date < '2015-06-14')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2015-06-15' LIMIT 0, 3)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2015-06-09' LIMIT 0, 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2015-06-09' LIMIT 0, 4)
UNION
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`date`) < '2015-06-07'
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`date`) < '2015-06-14' LIMIT 0, 1)
```

Comment: These were sample DB rows - as I said I don't know how many rows with the same date I have. Thanks anyway! (: